# How to get the sender phone number in SMSLib?

Tags: java, sms-gateway, smslib

I'm using SMSLib to read messages from a specified gateway, the piece of code used for reading the messages is :

```
List<InboundMessage> msgList = new ArrayList<InboundMessage>();

        Service.getInstance().readMessages(msgList, MessageClasses.ALL);
        for (InboundMessage msg : msgList)
            System.out.println(msg);
```

The point here that i want to get the phone number that send this message to the gateway, is that possible? and it yes, how?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `msg.getOriginator();`

Note that the SMS protocol does not require the phone number of the sender to be present,(and it might even be text, and not a phone number).

Comment: thx, by the way i wanted that for recording issues and nothing related to SMS protocol.